# Spring Boot SAML SSO custom JWT token refresh

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, single-sign-on, spring-saml

I have followed below URL to configure SAML SSO to the existing spring boot application, which already have User name - password authentication and JWT authorization for APIs.

https://github.com/pateluday07/saml-sso-and-slo-demo-idp-azure-sp-springboot

Also in onSSOSuccessHandler() I have generated custom JWT token and returned to the Angular front end as cookie. The JWT token expiry set for 1 Hour. The spring boot application is configured with stateless session policy.

On JWT token expiry how we can refresh the token by validating the SSO session? Do we have to call /saml/login endpoint on token expiry?